# see if file exist and create file in android

Tags: android, file, outputstream, file-exists

Hi i'm trying to create a file if the file not already exists. Then I want to write 11 zeros in 11 rows if the file not already existed and then read it to an 2d array. But the app crashes and i got the message "java.io.FileNotFoundException: /FILENAME: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)" in logcat. I would really appreciate if someone could help me.
Here is my code:

```
public void empt(String fileName) {

    File file = getBaseContext().getFileStreamPath(fileName);
    if(file.exists()){
        return 1;
    }
    else return 2;
 }


 public int[][] readFile2(String fileName) {

     empt(fileName);
     if(empty == 1){

         FileOutputStream outputStream;
         String row = "0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0";
         String newline = "\n";

         try {
           outputStream = openFileOutput(fileName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
           for(int i = 0; i <11; i++)
             {
                 if(i == 10){
                     outputStream.write(row.getBytes());
                 }
                 else {
                 outputStream.write(row.getBytes());
                 outputStream.write(line.getBytes());
                 }
             }
           outputStream.close();
         } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
         }

     }


      String line = "";
      int[][] data = new int [11][11];
      try {
       BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName)); 
      int i = 0;
       while((line = br.readLine()) != null) { // line becomes the whole line ( 11 numbers on a row)
        String[] theline = line.split(" "); // theline becomes an array with 11 numbers


            for(int k = 0; k<11; k++)
            {   
                data[i][k] = (Integer.parseInt(theline[k]));
            }
        i++;
       }
       br.close();
      }
      catch(FileNotFoundException fN) {
       fN.printStackTrace();
      }
      catch(IOException e) {
       System.out.println(e);
      }
      return data;
     }
```

Comment: Funny, I just answered a question like this.  Do you know that `File` does not create folders unless you call `mkDirs()`?  Please also tell us what value `fileName` has.

Comment: Regarding `empt()`, using class members to pass function results is *horribly* wrong (and will go *horribly* wrong). Please don't do that. Secondly, what's your file name?

Comment: My file name is not always the same i have a spinner with values all or 0-10 and for example if user choose 2 the filename becomes "two"

Answer (score 0):

to read from the internal storage you have to use `openFileInput`.

Change

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
```

with

```
FileInputStream fstream = openFileInput(fileName);
DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
```